# Running Tezos node with rolling mode but sync started at the beginning

Tags: baking, node, baking-node

I'm running the node by described here: 
https://medium.com/@Jamyye/install-tezos-node-on-ubuntu-18-04-rolling-history-mode-e26598daa3d2 
OR 
https://gist.github.com/hclivess/cfbc8eddb1f5692c619036cb47072934
with **rolling** mode but sync started at the beginning and already use 50GB. I checked timestamp: 
$ ./tezos-client get timestamp
2018–12–05T16:55:20Z
What I’m doing wrong?

Comment: I've had to take a snapshot and import it to garbage collect. Hopefully gc will happen automatically in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the history-mode argument when importing the snapshot. These are the steps:

```
rm -rf .tezos-node/{context,store,version.json}
tezos-node snapshot import "${SNAPSHOT_FILENAME}" --history-mode=experimental-rolling
tezos-node config init
tezos-node run --history-mode=experimental-rolling --rpc-addr=127.0.0.1:8732 --connections=20 --bootstrap-threshold=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that OP is importing a snapshot - seems OP simply wants to run a rolling node, and expects the node to sync itself with only the 5 latest cycles?